# Rendering json object name/description for each object in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

React newbie here. I have a component which gets an array of objects in JSON format and saves it into the state.

I am now unsure how I can render the name/description of each object in the components render function.

Any ideas?

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ishizaka-rfp3k - Demo

```
   return (
      <div className="App">
        {name1} // Object 1 name
        {description1} // Object 1 description
        {name2} // Object 2 name
        {description2} // Object 2 description
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through data(i.e. array of objects) and render them with your required properties of object.

Add a method which returns JSX for rendering profile data:

```
renderProfiles = () => {
    const profiles = this.state.profiles || [];
    const renderProfiles = profiles.map(profile => (
        <div key={profile.mainCompanyID}> // pass unique id as a key value
            {profile.name}
            {profile.description}
        </div>
    ));
    return renderProfiles;
};
```

And then add this to your main render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.renderProfiles()}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Full codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-sara-qjc7r

Comment: Thank you for tis. However, how could I render one profile at time though?

So I could render the 4th object name/description by its self?

Comment: Then simply you could do is `{profiles[3] && (<div>{profiles[3].name}{profiles[3].description}</div>)}`

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through the profiles array of objects by using map:

```
<div className="App">
        {this.state.profiles.map((profile, index) => 
          <p>{profile.name}
           {profile.description}</p>
        )}
        <br/>
      </div>
```

further detials about map function: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method and call that from render as:

```
  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.renderProfiles()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderProfiles = () => {
    return this.state.profiles.map((profile)=>{
      const {name,description} = profile;
      return (
        <div className="App">
        {name} 
        {description} 
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how I can render the name/description of each object in the
>   components render function.

You can use the `map()` function as follows:

```
this.state.profiles.map(item => {
        return(
          <div>{"Name: " + item.name + " description: " + item.description}</div>
        ) 
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 return (
  <div className="App">
    {profiles.map(({name, description}) => (
      <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function `getProfiles` you fetched the data and put that into the state a `profiles`. What you need to do then is to loop this array of data and render it like the following.

```js
render() {
  const { profiles } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {profiles.map(profile => (
        <div>
          <p>{profile.name}</p>
          <p>{profile.description}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

So for each profile in my `profiles` array, I will render a `div` with two `p` which will contains the `name` and `description`. This is just an example and you can modify the render as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You should [`#Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the profiles to `JSX`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { profiles: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProfiles();
  }

  getProfiles = () => {...};
  };

  render() {
    const { profiles } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {profiles.map(({ name, description }) => (
          <div style={{ border: '1px solid palegreen' }}>
            <div>Name:{name}</div>
            <div>Description: {description}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58284921-MapProfiles]

Answer (score 1):

```
  render() {
    const { profiles } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!this.state.profiles.length > 0
          ?
            (
              <div>
                <p>Loading...</p>
              </div>
            ))
          : profiles.map((data, key) => {
              return (
                <div key={key}>
                  <p>Name: {data.name}</p>
                  <p>Description: {data.description}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```